# are there card swipe events in .net

Tags: c#, swipe, smartcard

I have a winforms application developed in .net for which I need to provide a feature to allow the user to login based on an identity card swipe. The application also provides for a login screen. The functionality required is:

- Allow user to enter username/password and click login.
- swipe an ID card to a smart card reader attached to the pc.

The user will take either approach for logging in. On swiping the card the system will begin validating the user.

I want to know if there is any way my .net application can get an event that is triggered by the action of swiping a card. From what I know so far (correct me if I'm wrong), it gets a key_press event. But you get that even the keyboard's buttons are pressed! ...so how do I identify that the card reader recieved a swipe?

**EDIT**

Im not sure if the card reader has a driver or any other utility that comes along with it that will help me in detection of event raised. It looks like a plug and play device to me. Not even sure what make and model it is.

Comment: You didn't really provide enough information.  Does the card reader have some sort of a driver that you use to communicate with it?  How does the computer see it?

Comment: Im not sure if it has a driver. It looks like a plug and play device to me. Not even sure what make and model it is.

Comment: What port does it connect to?  Is it COM or USB for example?

Comment: Its connected to the USB port

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links>

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Smart-Cards-in-.NET/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/SmartcardFmwk.aspx